# 3Layer C# asp.net: insert dropdownlist selected text and value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a 3 Layer asp.net c# code. My BL:

```
    public DataTable ddl()
    {
        base.Link();
        string Query = "SELECT [nam], [idZone] FROM [zones] ORDER BY idZone";
        DataTable Output_Q = base.SelectDataText(Query);
        base.UnLink();
        return Output_Q;
    }
    public void insert()
    {
        base.Link();
        string Query = "INSERT INTO students (fnam, lnam, cod, idZone) VALUES ( '{0}', '{1}', '{2}', {3} )";
        Query = string.Format(Query, fnam, lnam, cod, idZone);
        base.commanddatatext(Query);
        base.UnLink();
```

My Code:

```
    page_load:
    BL_students_new F = new BL_students_new();
    DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
    DropDownList1.DataSource = F.ddl();
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "nam";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "idZone";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();

        btn_insert:
        BL_students_new F = new BL_students_new();
        F.fnam = TextBox1.Text.Trim();
        F.lnam = TextBox2.Text.Trim();
        F.cod = TextBox3.Text.Trim();
        F.idZone = Convert.ToInt32(DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value);
        F.insert();
```

it saves every things but dropdownlist value. note that my ddl has text and int value and i need the value to be saved. but it fails. (My DA is OK too.)

Comment: "Fails" how?  Specifically what happens?  Is there an error?  Is a record inserted but without that value?  When you debug, where specifically is the value lost?

Comment: @David it saves the first index of ddl. not my choise

Comment: Well, according to the code posted you save the record *immediately* after binding the list.  So you never have an opportunity to make a choice or enter any values.

Comment: @David i set F.idZone and then i call F.insert(). what should I do then?

Comment: You should insert your form values into the database *after* you've had a chance to actually interact with the form.  The lines of code in your last code snippet take about a millisecond to execute.  In that time, you haven't changed the selected value.  (Since this is ASP.NET, you haven't even seen the drop down list yet at this time.)  So by the time you select a value, that database insert was already performed.

Comment: @David I'm really sorry. i corrected my code. populating ddl is in page_load and inserting is in btn_insert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your comment above:

> populating ddl is in page_load and inserting is in btn_insert

`Page_Load` happens *before* `btn_Insert`.  [This happens *every* time the page is requested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx), regardless of whether it's a "post back" or not.  (After all, the page has to load into a usable state before it can even *know* the nature of the HTTP request.)

So what's happening is the following:

1. Bind the `DropDownList` options
2. Show the page to the user
3. User selects an option and submits
4. Re-bind the `DropDownList` options, losing whatever the user selected
5. Insert to database

A simple way to address this in WebForms is to wrap your `DropDownList` binding logic in a condition on `IsPostBack`.  Something like this:

```
// in Page_Load:
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    BL_students_new F = new BL_students_new();
    DropDownList1.Items.Clear();
    DropDownList1.DataSource = F.ddl();
    DropDownList1.DataTextField = "nam";
    DropDownList1.DataValueField = "idZone";
    DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
```

That way you're only populating the `DropDownList` when the page is initially requested, not when the user is submitting the form.